# Symfony 2 config parameter - The parameter must be defined

Tags: symfony

I have a Bundle called Web\CoworkerBundle. In DIC/Configuration.php I have:

```
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('web_coworker');
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->scalarNode('redirect_url')->defaultNull()->end()
    ->end();
```

In config.yml I have:

```
web_coworker:
    redirect_url: "http://www.example.com/"
```

Now in my DefaultController.php, I do

```
return array(
    'url' => $this->container->getParameter('redirect_url')
);
```

I get the error

> The parameter "redirect_url" must be defined.

Do I miss something?

Comment: Is that OK that you have typo in `        ->scalarstackoNde('redirect_url')->defaultNull()->end()` ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy-paste error :) Fixed it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to create an extension in your bundle (*Acme/DemoBundle/DependencyInjection*)

```
class AcmeDemoBundleExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
        // MOST IMPORTANT LINE
        $container->setParameter('web_coworker.params', $config);
    }
}
```

Now concerning the controller you can remove what your were returning and that should do the trick :)

Comment: The "most important line" isn't in the example in the Cookbook!  You may also need to flatten the first level of your arrays, take a look at how the FOS User Bundle does this.